# preg_replace: all after first "-"

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I have:

```
$text = "1235-text1-text2-a1-780-c-text3";
```

How can I get this with preg_replace? It is necessary to redirect 301.

```
"text1-text2-a1-780-c-text3"
```

Comment: [this](https://regex101.com/r/qF9qG0/1)

Comment: you get example for before replace.

Comment: `trim(strstr($text, '-'), '-');`

Comment: Please put some effort in asking a good & clear question.

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score 0):

for no use regex you can try

```
trim(strstr($text, '-'),'-');
```

Answer (score 0):

No Regex needed:

```
$result = substr($text, strpos($text, '-')+1);
```

Or:

```
$result = trim(strstr($text, '-'), '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
[^-]*-
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qF9qG0/2)**

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/[^-]*-/"; 
$text = "1235-text1-text2-a1-780-c-text3"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, "", $text, 1);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/T58XvM)**

Answer (score 0):

Or use preg_match

```
<?php
$text = "1235-text1-text2-a1-780-c-text3";

preg_match("%[^-]*-(.*)%",$text, $matchs);
var_dump($matchs[1]);
// Output "text1-text2-a1-780-c-text3"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted, using preg_replace:

```
$re = '/^([\w]*-)/';
$str = "1235-text1-text2-a1-780-c-text3";
$match = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
var_dump($match);
```

An alternative using preg_match:

```
$re = '/-(.*)/';
$str = "1235-text1-text2-a1-780-c-text3";
preg_match($re,$str,$matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```